# Perform same data augmentation in tf.data for CSV image files for both input and reference images

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow2.0, data-augmentation

For the training of my model I want to perform data augmentation on the data set to improve performance. My input data instances consist of snapshots of wave height, saved in CSV (a 160x160 grid), which is the same for my labels/reference data.

For that reason I want to perform the same data augmentation procedure on each input-label pair. However, I am not finding any good way to load my csv data (basically simply as a 160,160 tensor) into the data api of tensorflow, so I tried a detour with pandas.

Here is some code of how I had expected it to work:

```py
...
input_files = ['./Data/input_{}.csv'.format(i) for i in range(1, 200)]
label_files = ['./Data/label_{}.csv'.format(i) for i in range(1, 200)]


def add_offset(img):
    offset = tf.random.uniform([1], 0, 5) * tf.ones(shape)
    return img + offset

# Load a data set instance and perform same data augmentation on input and label
def load(file_path):
    # Detour with pandas' read_csv -> tf.io.read_file + decode_csv don't work for arrays
    img = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, delim_whitespace=False).values
    img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img)
    return img

def augment(file_path1, file_path2):
    img = tf.stack([load(file_path1), load(file_path2)])
    # Augment only a certain percentage
    if tf.random.uniform(1) < 0.1: 
        img = add_offset(img)
    
    return img[0], img[1]


train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_files, label_files))
train_data = train_data.map(lambda x, y: augment(x, y)).batch(1)
...
```

The error that I get is that the passed file_path in `pd.read_csv` is not a valid file path and indeed, it seems to be some kind of tensor. Any ideas on how to load the csv data as arrays and to perform the same data augmentation on both inputs and labels?

Edit: The error message reads

```py
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

And here is a small part of one of my csv files. The values range in general from 0.5 to 5.

```
1.393020,1.389099,1.386132,1.383231,1.380271
1.394938,1.392077,1.389846,1.387650,1.385154
1.395655,1.393057,1.391297,1.389553,1.387415
1.396266,1.393928,1.392303,1.390782,1.388740
1.396814,1.394653,1.393193,1.391659,1.389615
```

2nd Edit: Some additional information on how I obtain my CSV files. They come from a coastal wave simulation, that give me the wave heights in a 160x160 grid / array as seen above. I can easily open them with Pandas or numpy without any problem. Now I had to change my script, since I have to much data to simply load it into memory. That is why I would like to use tf.data, but I got stuck with the problem mentioned above.

Comment: Seems like the CSV isn't a CSV. Please include the actual error, and if it's not too big, a sample of the CSV. Is the CSV like a bitmap?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I included the error message and a sub-array of one of my csv files. Would this type of file work with bitmap? The problem is also that I have some NaNs, which is why I tried to avoid image formats.

Comment: That’s not a CSV file, that’s something else. A CSV is just values separated by a delimiter (usually a comma, hence **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alue). That looks like someone printed a data structure straight out of a program, like `print([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], file=‘data.csv’) `. You first need to figure out how convert that to data you can feed to Pandas. I don’t know what `array ` is. Is that a Tensor or Numpy structure?

Comment: Thanks for yout patience! Indeed, I did not explain it well. I added some additional information to make the problem more clear hopefully. I just copy-pasted part of the array that I can read from the CSV file with pandas/numpy, which is why it was shown as a numpy structure. The problem is that the file path passed to `pd.read_csv` is some kind of tensor instance that pandas can't work with.